# Select all days from a table missing some dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with data like below, and I'm trying to sum up column b and group by day.  This works great.  However some days have no data in the table at all.  I want to show these days as having the sum 0, but I'm a bit confused on how to get there.

```
Date,  column b
05/24/90, 5
05/24/90, 27
05/26/90, 19
05/27/90, 24
```

What I want to have in the end is

```
05/24/90, 32
05/25/90, 0
05/25/90, 19
05/27/90, 24
```

etc...

Comment: Use a numbers table, or generate one with a CTE, to produce a set of all of the dates in the desired range. Then you can join your existing table with the dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - show rows for missing dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038494/sql-server-show-rows-for-missing-dates)

Comment: I actually just created a dates table covering the entire range I need, however, I'm having trouble getting the join right.  Either I get the same data I was getting, or I get out only the dates that don't exist in the table above...      `select d.dt as date, sum(a.colb) from dates as d left join tablea as a group by date order by date`

Comment: Always use aliases with joins. You have a lot of `date` references floating around: `select d.dt as date, sum(a.colb) from dates as d left outer join tablea as a on a.Date = d.dt group by d.dt order by d.dt`. (Also missing the `on` clause.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = (SELECT MIN([date]) FROM yourTable);
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE = (SELECT MAX([date]) FROM yourTable);

WITH CTE_dates
AS
(
    SELECT @MinDate dates
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,dates)
    FROM CTE_dates
    WHERE dates < @MaxDate
)

SELECT  A.dates,
        SUM(ISNULL(B.[column b],0))
FROM CTE_dates A
LEFT JOIN yourTable
    ON A.dates = B.dates
GROUP BY A.dates
```

Comment: Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at MSDN Blogs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).