# get the value from the previous row if row is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

I have this pivoted table

```
+---------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| Date    | Product1 | Product2 | ... | ProductN |
+---------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| 7/1/15  | 5        | 2        | ... | 7        |
| 8/1/15  | 7        | 1        | ... | 9        |
| 9/1/15  | NULL     | 7        | ... | NULL     |
| 10/1/15 | 8        | NULL     | ... | NULL     |
| 11/1/15 | NULL     | NULL     | ... | NULL     |
+---------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
```

I wanted to fill in the `NULL` column with the values above them. So, the output should be something like this.

```
+---------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| Date    | Product1 | Product2 | ... | ProductN |
+---------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
| 7/1/15  | 5        | 2        | ... | 7        |
| 8/1/15  | 7        | 1        | ... | 9        |
| 9/1/15  | 7        | 7        | ... | 9        |
| 10/1/15 | 8        | 7        | ... | 9        |
| 11/1/15 | 8        | 7        | ... | 9        |
+---------+----------+----------+-----+----------+
```

I've found this [article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/filling-in-missing-values-using-the-t-sql-window-frame/) that might help me but this only manipulate one column. How do I apply this to all my column or how can I achieve such result since my columns are dynamic.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that it would be a lot easier to do this before pivoting.

Comment: Yes. But I cannot find any way on how to determined what are the `NULL` columns

Comment: It's the rows that don't exist in the original data (assuming you don't actually have NULL values there)

Comment: It is possible to determine what are the rows that do not exists? An example would be a great reference.

Comment: It depends on your data, but for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038494/sql-server-show-rows-for-missing-dates has some ideas. You could also consider creating a calendar table (1 row per day), it usually helps in calendar related queries

Comment: @JamesZ I'll give this a try. Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI standard has the `IGNORE NULLS` option on `LAG()`.  This is *exactly* what you want.  Alas, SQL Server has not (yet?) implemented this feature.

So, you can do this in several ways.  One is using multiple `outer apply`s.  Another uses correlated subqueries:

```
select p.date,
       (case when p.product1 is not null else p.product1
             else (select top 1 p2.product1 from pivoted p2 where p2.date < p.date order by p2.date desc)
        end) as product1,
       (case when p.product1 is not null else p.product1
             else (select top 1 p2.product1 from pivoted p2 where p2.date < p.date order by p2.date desc)
        end) as product1,
       (case when p.product2 is not null else p.product2
             else (select top 1 p2.product2 from pivoted p2 where p2.date < p.date order by p2.date desc)
        end) as product2,
       . . .
from pivoted p ;
```

I would recommend an index on `date` for this query.

Comment: Hi. How would you do this dynamically? Since I do not know what are the `Products`.

Comment: @BoyPasmo . . . That would be a very different question.  I would suggest that you ask the question *and* include the code you are using for the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you a solution. If you have a table which consists of merely two columns my solution will work perfectly.

```
+---------+----------+
| Date    | Product  |
+---------+----------+
| 7/1/15  | 5        |
| 8/1/15  | 7        |
| 9/1/15  | NULL     |
| 10/1/15 | 8        |
| 11/1/15 | NULL     |
+---------+----------+

select  x.[Date], 
        case
            when x.[Product] is null
            then min(c.[Product])
        else
            x.[Product]
        end as Product
from
(
    -- this subquery evaluates a minimum distance to the rows where Product column contains a value
    select  [Date], 
            [Product], 
            min(case when delta >= 0 then delta else null end) delta_min,
            max(case when delta < 0 then delta else null end) delta_max
    from
    (
        -- this subquery maps Product table to itself and evaluates the difference between the dates
        select  p.[Date],
                p.[Product], 
                DATEDIFF(dd, p.[Date], pnn.[Date]) delta
        from @products p
        cross join (select * from @products where [Product] is not null) pnn
    ) x
    group by [Date], [Product]
) x
left join @products c on x.[Date] = 
    case
        when abs(delta_min) < abs(delta_max) then DATEADD(dd, -delta_min, c.[Date]) 
        else DATEADD(dd, -delta_max, c.[Date])
    end
group by x.[Date], x.[Product]
order by x.[Date]
```

In this query I mapped the table to itself rows which contain values by CROSS JOIN statement. Then I calculated differences between dates in order to pick the closest ones and thereafter fill empty cells with values.

Result:

```
+---------+----------+
| Date    | Product  |
+---------+----------+
| 7/1/15  | 5        |
| 8/1/15  | 7        |
| 9/1/15  | 7        |
| 10/1/15 | 8        |
| 11/1/15 | 8        |
+---------+----------+
```

Actually, the suggested query doesn't choose the previous value. Instead of this, it selects the closest value. In other words, my code can be used for a number of different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
First You need to add identity column in temporary or hard table then resolved by following method.

--- Solution ----

Create Table #Test (ID Int Identity (1,1),[Date] Date , Product_1 INT )

Insert Into #Test ([Date], Product_1)
Values
('7/1/15',5)
,('8/1/15',7)
,('9/1/15',Null)
,('10/1/15',8)
,('11/1/15',Null)


Select ID , DATE , 
IIF ( Product_1 is null ,
(Select Product_1 from #TEST
Where ID = (Select Top 1 a.ID From #TEST a where a.Product_1 is not null and a.ID<b.ID
Order By a.ID desc)
),Product_1) Product_1
from #Test b


-- Solution End ---
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).